# Someone who enjoys competing with others

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, word-difference

I wonder what do you call a person who is interested in completeling with others in every aspect of their life; (uch an individual might love doing that). They can be either deceitful and act insincerely or act as a real competitor as their character requires. We call such a person: **a man of contest or a man of competition** figuratively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just say they are 'competitive' or 'ambitious'.

Comment: Arw your two adjective mean the same in this sense @James?

Comment: I think ambitious is generally a positive characteristic. While competitive can be seen as positive or negative. So I think the distinction is left up to the person writing it.